# How to break the execution of the code based on a user input

Tags: java

So I am doing a digit counter thing basically
I want it to display 123 and which number is what place value for example 123

```
------------------------------------
Enter any number: 123
Ones: 3
Tens: 2
Hundreds: 1
------------------------------------
```

this is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class digits {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter any number: ");
        
        int number = scann.nextInt();
        
        int num1 = number % 10;
        int num2 = number / 10 % 10;
        int num3 = number / 100 % 10;
        int num4 = number / 1000 % 10;
        int num5 = number / 10000 % 10;
        int num6 = number / 100000 % 10;
        int num7 = number / 1000000 % 10;
        int num8 = number / 10000000 % 10;
        scann.close();
        
        System.out.println("Ones: "+num1);
        System.out.println("Tens: "+num2);
        System.out.println("Hundreds: "+num3);
        System.out.println("Thousands: "+num4);
        System.out.println("Ten-Thousands: "+num5);
        System.out.println("Hundred-Thousands: "+num6);
        System.out.println("Millions: "+num7);
        System.out.println("Ten-Millions: "+num8);

        }
    }
```

How do I stop it from printing the rest if I only type 123?

Output I got

```
--------------------------
Enter any number: 123
Ones: 3
Tens: 2
Hundreds: 1
Thousands: 0
Ten-Thousands: 0
Hundred-Thousands: 0
Millions: 0
Ten-Millions: 0
------------------------
```

Output I want

```
--------------------------
Enter any number: 123
Ones: 3
Tens: 2
Hundreds: 1
------------------------
```

Comment: I'm not sure "*How do I stop it from printing the rest if I only type 123?*" is understandable question.

Comment: Please [edit] to add useful info to the question.

Comment: You could convert the number to a string, check how many digits it's got, and then only print for that number of digits.  i.e.  Do a `if(str.length() >= 2) then print the tens`

Comment: And now i have a familiy emgency thanks for the help ill see if I can get it to work with multiple number later

Comment: @Geokit - Hey, welcome to SO. Sorry if this community seems harsh with the downvotes. Try not to let it bother you too much. Ask more questions if you need to know stuff, but follow the [guide for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). They really mean it about that "Minimal, complete and verifiable example" part. Good edits so far, but the title could be better.

Answer (score 2):

You need to introduce a condition (or conditions) in your code.

You can achieve that with a chain of **if** statements. But the better way to do it is by utilizing a **loop**. Because that will allow you to *get rid of the intermediate variables* (`num1`, `num2`, etc) and to *avoid duplicating* the line of code that prints the remainder on the consol. That will make the code more readable and concise.

In order to be able to apply the **loop** for this problem, you need to create an **array** of strings that will store all quantifiers *("Ones: ", "Tens: ", etc)*.

It can be done like that:

```
public static final String[] quantifiers =
           {"Ones: ", "Tens: ", "Hundreds: ", "Thousands: ",
            "Ten-Thousands: ", "Hundred-Thousands: ", "Millions: ", "Ten-Millions: "};
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scann.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < quantifiers.length && number > 0; i++) {
        System.out.println(quantifiers[i] + number % 10);
        number /= 10; // does the same as number = number / 10;
    }
}
```

**output** for input 123

```
Ones: 3
Tens: 2
Hundreds: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing all the numbers because that's what you wrote:

```java
System.out.println("Ones: "+num1);
```

...and so on.

If you never want to print e.g. thousands, just remove the `println` for thousands. If you only want to print them if someone actually enters thousands, add an `if` statement:

```java
if (num4 > 0) {
   System.out.println("Thousands: "+num4);
}
```

Repeat for the others.

Answer (score 0):

It might help your question. Because of hardcoded terms such as 'tens' or 'hundreds', it is not generic enough.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter any number: ");

    int number = scann.nextInt();

    int length = String.valueOf(number).length();

    for(int i=0; i< length; i++){

        if(i == 0){
            System.out.println("Ones: "+ number % 10);
        }else if(i == 1)
            System.out.println("Tens: " + number / 10 % 10);
        else if(i == 2)
            System.out.println("Hundreds: "+  number / 100 % 10);
        else if(i == 3)
            System.out.println("Thousands: "+ number / 1000 % 10);
        else if(i == 4)
            System.out.println("Ten-Thousands: "+ number / 10000 % 10);
        else if(i == 5)
            System.out.println("Hundred-Thousands: "+ number / 100000 % 10);
        else if(i == 6)
            System.out.println("Millions: "+ number / 1000000 % 10);
        else if(i == 7)
            System.out.println("Ten-Millions: " + number / 10000000 % 10);
    }
    scann.close();

}
```

Comment: and that is more generic? not hardcoded? just a more complicated way to write a sequence of statements - remove the `for` and the `if`s, you get the same result (probably even a bit faster then suggested here,)